# Is “I have eaten more cake than I am willing to say.” intelligible?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I am an English native who is on a journey of learning English grammar for the first time.

**Does “I have eaten more cake than I am willing to say.” make sense?**

I am not 100% sure if the **above** sentence is intelligible and I know that to find out the answer I must either receive an answer from this helpful community or receive the name of the area of grammar I must research to find the answer myself. Thus, if you could provide either, that would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Does "more" mean occurrences or quantity? I.e., have you eaten a lot of cake (in one sitting) or lots of cakes over time?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, and Merry Christmas. .The quotes in the question's title and text have different word order. Both are intelligible, though the "more" in the title's word order can quantify the amount of cake or something more philosophical about eating cake. Please [edit] the question to make the title consistent with the text.

Comment: @SEnglish: You need to [merge your accounts](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). That's why you can't automatically edit your own question.

Comment: The quoted sentence certainly makes sense, but not your question. What is it about the sentence that you want a "rule" to define? Please edit your post to clarify what you're unsure about.

Comment: It rather depends what it is that you are trying to say.  It could mean that you you do not want to reveal how much cake you have eaten.  But, in telling me that you are not willing to tell me this, you have, in effect, told me what you wanted to conceal:  that you have eaten far too much.  So it does, in a way not make 'logical sense'.  But, as a kind of rhetorical hyperbole, it works.

Comment: You might hear something like "I've eaten more cake **than I care to admit**,"

Comment: Yes: it makes sense. Syntactically, it's a comparative construction, where "I am willing to say" is an obligatorily reduced comparative clause functioning as complement of "than". If the ellipsis were filled out, the result would be something like (the ungrammatical) *"I have eaten more cake than I am willing to say I have eaten cake".

Answer (score 1):

A good question for Xmas day.

It reflects my own Xmas reality:

**Truth**: I have eaten some Xmas cake.

**Truth**: I admit that I have eaten some Xmas cake.

**Limited Truth**: I am willing to admit to some measure of how much cake I ate. For example, I might say "a piece", "a few mouthfuls", "a morsel", "a bit".

**Hidden Truth**: I am not willing to admit that I ate 250 grams of Xmas cake, for that might sound greedy.

Given the complexity of truths, partial truths, hidden truths and unexpressed feelings (of shame or guilt in eating too much, for example), I suspect that there is no grammatical rule to encapsulate this structure, even though it is understandable and correctly expressed.